# Measuring the semantic similarity of two strings in c#

Tags: c#, nlp

I've been using the Levenstein Distance to measure the similarity of two strings.

```
int ComputeLevenshteinDistance(string source, string target)
{
    if ((source == null) || (target == null)) return 0;
    if ((source.Length == 0) || (target.Length == 0)) return 0;
    if (source == target) return source.Length;

    int sourceWordCount = source.Length;
    int targetWordCount = target.Length;

    // Step 1
    if (sourceWordCount == 0)
        return targetWordCount;

    if (targetWordCount == 0)
        return sourceWordCount;

    int[,] distance = new int[sourceWordCount + 1, targetWordCount + 1];

    // Step 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= sourceWordCount; distance[i, 0] = i++);
    for (int j = 0; j <= targetWordCount; distance[0, j] = j++);

    for (int i = 1; i <= sourceWordCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= targetWordCount; j++)
        {
            // Step 3
            int cost = (target[j - 1] == source[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

            // Step 4
            distance[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(distance[i - 1, j] + 1, distance[i, j - 1] + 1), distance[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }

    return distance[sourceWordCount, targetWordCount];
}
```

But I would like to either modify or write a new code that measures the semantic similarity of two strings with percentage given.

I tried to search some code samples on web, but it was hard to find a simple one that has some semantic similarity measurement functionality.

What is a clear and simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the algorithm myself to find the closest string. It is extremely useful in ICR/OCR documents. To sort string I had to sort string by similarity, sorting input based only on edit distance was not enough. I figured, given both strings normalized, that maximum edit distance between two given strings is equal to the length of the longest string, and minimum is, well, zero. So, I had just converted edit distance to percentage by dividing it to maximum distance.

It is a naive solution but it works extremely well. In ICR/OCR we have some false positives like `h` becomes `ln`, `m` becomes `rn`, etc... I did not have to worry about them, not anymore.

PS: String normalization was, in my case, was to remove all symbols, and converting to uppercase ASCII letters.